# Generating a lagged time series cross sectional variable in R

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data, plm

I am a new R user.  I have a time series cross-sectional dataset and, although I have found ways to lag time series data in `R`, I have not found a way to create lagged time-series cross-sectional variables so that I can use them in my analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you could use the `lag()` function with `zoo` (and panel series data):

```
> library(plm)
> library(zoo)
> data("Produc")
> dnow <- pdata.frame(Produc)
> x.Date <- as.Date(paste(rownames(t(as.matrix(dnow$pcap))), "-01-01", sep=""))
> x <- zoo(t(as.matrix(dnow$pcap)), x.Date)
> x[1:3,1:3]
            ALABAMA  ARIZONA ARKANSAS
1970-01-01 15032.67 10148.42  7613.26
1971-01-01 15501.94 10560.54  7982.03
1972-01-01 15972.41 10977.53  8309.01
```

Lag forward by 1:

```
> lag(x[1:3,1:3],1)
            ALABAMA  ARIZONA ARKANSAS
1970-01-01 15501.94 10560.54  7982.03
1971-01-01 15972.41 10977.53  8309.01
```

Lag backward by 1:

```
> lag(x[1:3,1:3],k=-1)
            ALABAMA  ARIZONA ARKANSAS
1971-01-01 15032.67 10148.42  7613.26
1972-01-01 15501.94 10560.54  7982.03
```

As Dirk mentioned, be careful with the meaning of lag in the different time series packages.  Notice how `xts` treats this differently:

```
> lag(as.xts(x[1:3,1:3]),k=1)
            ALABAMA  ARIZONA ARKANSAS
1970-01-01       NA       NA       NA
1971-01-01 15032.67 10148.42  7613.26
1972-01-01 15501.94 10560.54  7982.03
```

Comment: Just be careful about the meaning of the lap operator is zoo:   "Note the sign of ‘k’: a series lagged by a positive ‘k’ is shifted      _earlier_ in time."

Comment: The question is about cross-sectional time-series (a.k.a. panel) data. afaik zoo does not handle this kind of data (due to repeated time observations).

Answer (score 4):

For cross-sectional time-series data the package [plm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/) is very useful. It has a lag function that takes into account the panel nature of the data.

```
library(plm)
data("Produc", package="plm")
dnow <- pdata.frame(Produc)
head(lag(dnow$pcap,1))
             ALABAMA-1970 ALABAMA-1971 ALABAMA-1972 ALABAMA-1973 ALABAMA-1974 
          NA     15032.67     15501.94     15972.41     16406.26     16762.67
```

One problem with the package is that using with (or within or transform) gives you the wrong answer.

```
head(with(dnow, lag(pcap,1)))
15032.67 15501.94 15972.41 16406.26 16762.67 17316.26
```

So be careful.